# How to discover in a trigger whether the NULL value was passed to a nullable column?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, null

How can one figure out in a BEFORE INSERT Trigger, whether the user has passed the NULL - value for an null-able column  **explicit**, or whether the user hasn't pass any value at all for that column.

In other words, I will be able to do following:

```
create table t (id, NUMBER, str VARCHAR2(30) );

create Trigger trg 
befor INSERT on t
FOR earch row
DECLARE
BEGIN
IF :NEW.str is NULL
THEN
  IF <NULL-Value was explicit passed> THEN
    dbms_output.put_line( 'user has passed NULL');
  ELSE 
    dbms_output.put_line( 'user has passed nothing');
  END IF;
END IF;
END;
/
```

and then after

```
INSERT INTO t (id, str) VALUES (1, NULL);
```

I will see

```
> user has passed NULL
```

and after

```
INSERT INTO t (id) VALUES (1);
```

I will see

```
> user has passed nothing
```

Comment: This is better done in your calling application than in SQL...

Comment: I don't think you can distinguish these two cases in Oracle.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no possibility to change the applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way in Oracle to *programmatically* distinguish a NULL deliberately passed from a defaulted NULL.

Apart from anything else, it would ascribe meaning to NULL when NULL defiantly remains the absence of meaning.  Why would you want to do that?

---

@OneDayWhen sez:

> "Codd himself proposed a second type
>   of NULL to mean 'inapplicable'"

Yes, a "This page intentionally left blank" for databases.  Apparently towards the end of his life Codd had identified four different types of NULL. 8-)

Other flavours of RDBMS distinguish between empty string and NULL, and perhaps some places have a convention that empty string means "inapplicable" and NULL means nothing.   However, Oracle treats empty string as NULL and nobody has implemented Codd's NULL2.  So I think it is dangerous to ascribe meaning to NULL in Oracle.

There are some database theorists who think NULL was one of Codd's big mistakes, and that goes double for different types of NULL.  For an interesting alternative take on the topic try reading Chris Date's [How To Handle Missing Information Without Using NULL](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Missing-info-without-nulls.pdf)

Comment: I have a view and an instead of insert trigger on a view. In the trigger i must insert values in a column that have a default value (1) but can contain also NULLs. And I have to distinguish whether the value of that column has been explicit set to NULL by inserting in the VIEW, or has been omitted by inserting in the view  and i have to set the value of the column to NULL in first case or to default value (1) in the second case.

Comment: "Why would you want to do that?" -- Codd himself proposed a second type of NULL to mean 'inapplicable' (as distinct from his original NULL that made it into SQL meaning a placeholder for a missing value). If you are interested in why Codd wanted to do that you will find a lot has been written about it.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to use a trigger for this, rather than a default value on the table column? Based on your comments to APC's answer, isn't this what you're trying to achieve?

```
create table t(id number, str varchar2(32) default 'default value');
create view v as select * from t;

insert into t(id) values (1);
insert into t(id, str) values (2,null);

insert into v(id) values (3);
insert into v(id, str) values (4,null);

select * from t;

ID                     STR                              
---------------------- -------------------------------- 
1                      default value                    
2                                                       
3                      default value                    
4
```

Comment: Yes, but I have an intermediate step a View. The problem is that the applications made there insert in a view and not in table. And a trigger on a view have to propagate that inserts to the underlying tables. In the Trigger i have to distinguish this two cases.

Comment: You can still have the default defined on the underling table. I've updated my answer. I don't understand what the trigger is adding here.

Comment: If you want to propagate the values to other tables you can use an before-insert or after-insert trigger on the table and reference `:new.str`, which will already have either null or the default value. If you're trying to use an instead-of trigger on the view you *could* use a magic-value default, I suppose, but that doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: in my case the view is based on a complex query and couldn't be inserted direct. That's why I need a instead of Trigger to propagate the insert to the underlying tables.

Comment: @Alex Poole: could you explain please what the _magic-value default_ is. This sounds exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: OK, asking about a before-insert trigger is just confusing then. I don't think you can make the distinction at all, unfortnately.

Comment: What I meant by *magic value default* wouldn't be necessary for a simple updatable view, and wouldn't be available for a complex view. So, er, ignore that part *8-)

Comment: I've thought this would be clearer if I ask the question more generally about the before trigger :) Thank you any way.

Comment: @schruik - the DEFAULT clause for a column is covered in the documentation: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#sthref5081

Comment: +1 - if it is possible to change the table definition, use=ing the DEFAULT clause is the way to go

Comment: @APC: is it possible to define the DEFAULT value on a VIEW column ?